# How to set a timeout to stop a function when it is running for some time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, timeout

I am using VS2008 and mainly MFC API. I have a function to read files from a FTP Host that was connected through LAN cable with CInternetSessions. I have set the FTP timeout value with the code:

```
dWtm = 4000; 

InternetSession->SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_DATA_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, dWtm);
```

And I included a delay in my get file function with `Sleep(10000)`. However, there was no timeout after 4seconds and the program continued to run normally.
I'm aware that I'm using the older version of C++ so I don't get access to functions like <thread and <chrono in C++11. Is AfxBeginThread applicable to create another thread that terminates the get file function after specified period? I've read something about it but was not sure how to use it in the code.
Please let me know if I'm not being specific on my questions and I will try to be more specific

EDIT: Code Snippet for getting the files from FTP

```
CInternetSession sess(_T("My FTP Session"));
CFtpConnection *pConnect = NULL;

try
{
   pConnect = sess.GetFtpConnection(lpServerName        
                        ,   lpUserName          
                        ,   lpPassword          
                        ,   nPort               
                        ,   TRUE);

   // use a file find object to enumerate files
   CFtpFileFind finder(pConnect);

   // start looping
   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(_T("*"));

   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
      _tprintf_s(_T("%s\n"), (LPCTSTR)finder.GetFileURL());
   }
}
catch (CInternetException *pEx)
{
   TCHAR sz[1024];
   pEx->GetErrorMessage(sz, 1024);
   _tprintf_s(_T("ERROR!  %s\n"), sz);
   pEx->Delete();
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing in C++, for the simple reason that it violates C++'s fundamental design: objects that get constructed in automatic scope must be destroyed before the automatic scope finishes. Whatever function you want to work this way, it must be explicitly coded to periodically check how long it's taking, and then return an error indication of some kind when it expires.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's odd because I've set the connection timeout when connecting to FTP server with the same method and it succeeds. It did timeout when the connection period exceeds the timeout period I've set. But when it comes to receiving data, it won't timeout even if I set Sleep to 60 seconds and timeout to 40 seconds.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you have any example to code it explicitly?

Comment: I may have misunderstand your problem but what if you have a standart class to use your ftp function.
Just construct it, 
Launch its function in a new thread, 
call another timed callback function that will just terminate the thread if need and call destructor, and finally join the thread ?

Comment: [There are still people who think that there are valid scenarios for calling `Terminate­Thread`.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811) Though, of course, there aren't. Which means your proposed solution won't work. Then again, we don't know what the problem really is, since you avoided showing us.

Comment: @IInspectable the problem I'm facing is that it sometimes take a long time to get a file from FTP server and I can't find a way to stop it from getting the file after a period of time. Example: the program is downloading the file from FTP server for more than 1minute, I want it to stop executing file download after 30 seconds. Please let me know what I should have included to make it more obvious.

Comment: Can you show us your function to download ?

Comment: @Goozzi i've edited my questions, hope it 's better

Comment: Do the function findNextFile() block for 1 minute ?

Comment: @Goozzi No, it doesn't. I forgot to include the Sleep(60000) in this snippet, I added the sleep myself to test if the timeout works. The code executes smoothly most of the time but was facing some issues sometimes.

Comment: I found this link : https://programmersheaven.com/discussion/180405/how-to-know-progress-of-cftpconnection-getfile
You probably can control the elapsed time in the second loop and abort if your custom timeout is reached

Comment: The software library you are using to implement an FTP download must not have sufficiently robust timeout capabilities. There's nothing you can do about it, unless you research the software library's documentation and find some other configuration setting that relates to timeouts. In absence of that, there's nothing you can do except to implement FTP yourself, using whatever timeout capabilities you need. Alternatively, you can fork off a new process to handle the FTP download, and kill the process if it doesn't finish before you give up. Those are your choices.